# Different users seem to have different views of the same JIRA board

Tags: jira

I administer a small JIRA installation - JIRA 7.6 Server on Centos 7.  One of my users is seeing a different view of the same board that other users see.  Specifically, most users see board DX with columns "To Do", "In Progress", "Review", and "Done".  One user sees the same board with columns "To Do", "In Progress", **"Code Review"**, and "Done" (and "Code Review" is a different workflow state than "Review" in this project.)

I'm not able to see how this user is configured to see the board differently.  Any ideas?

I'll note that I've seen several questions asking "is it possible for there to be different views of the same board", where the answer seems to be "create another board."  Here, I believe we have only a single board but different users are seeing it differently.  I believe these to be the same board; they have the same title and the same description/subtitle, and a search as JIRA Admin from the "View All Boards" page for "Blue" yields this board and one other board for a different project.

Thank you.

My view:
[image]
Users view:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in fact two different boards.  The board name is not what's in big print; that is the sprint, which can be switched.  The board name is in little print above the sprint name - in one case "Blue Team" and in the other case "JET Board".